# How to print of all ternary number of 100 digits?

Tags: list-manipulation, number-bases

For example, to print all ternary number of 3 digits I would do something like this

```
Do[Do[Do[Print[i, j, k], {k, 0, 2}], {j, 0, 2}], {i, 0, 2}]
```

to return 000, 001, 002,010,011,...

But I how to do it if I want the ternary numbers of 100 digits? It would be to hard to do it in the same way I did in the 3 digits case.

Comment: You want *all* ternary numbers with 100 digits? Isn't that `3^100` different numbers?!

Comment: `list = Tuples[{0,1,2}, n]` does what you want, where `n` is the number of digits. But don't do this with `n=100`.

Comment: Or to get it in the same form you as your post, `Scan[Print[Sequence @@ #] &, Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 100]]`. And I agree with @march, you're going to crash your machine with n=100.

Comment: @N.J.Evans. You're going to crash the universe with `n=100`!

Comment: I don't really want n=100. I want from 1 to 15. 100 was just one example.

Comment: @march 100! ? challange accepted: `Tuples[{0,1,2}, 100!]`

Comment: If you do all of them between `1` and `15`, that is a list of length `21 523 359`. Perhaps that's manageable?

Comment: @paw. NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!

Comment: @march It may be a manageable number, but I assume OP is going somewhere with this, and I'm kind of curious if this is the best means to his final end.

Comment: @N.J.Evans. Agreed. I guess we'll see where this takes us.

Comment: I want to calculate the first 15 homologic group of a graph, for that I need to see what are the regular allowed n-paths (n from 1 to 15). My graph has 3 vertices, for that I need to know the intersection of the boundary of each regular n-allowed path space with the (n-1)-allowed set (that can be seen as (n-1)-digits ternary numbers).
I will put less edges to make it easier to calculate.

Comment: @AndréGomes - if you are hoping for a response to your follow-on question then you need to ask it as a new question. Very few people will look at -- and fewer respond to -- a question in the comments section.

Comment: @BobHanlon I'm not joping for an answer to my follow-on question. Thanks. I was just expaining what I was doind, once people said that my approach might not be the best. I was showing that I really needed all those 3-uples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
n = 3;
list = Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, n];
```

To get numbers rather than lists of digits:

```
list2 = FromDigits /@ list

(*  {0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 100, 101, 102, 110, 111, 112, 120, 121, \
122, 200, 201, 202, 210, 211, 212, 220, 221, 222}  *)
```

Or

```
BaseForm[#, 3] & /@ Range[0, 3^n - 1]
```

[image]

To pad with leading 0's

```
IntegerString[#, 3, n] & /@ Range[0, 3^n - 1]

(*  {"000", "001", "002", "010", "011", "012", "020", "021", "022", \
"100", "101", "102", "110", "111", "112", "120", "121", "122", "200", \
"201", "202", "210", "211", "212", "220", "221", "222"}  *)
```

Or

```
IntegerString[#, 10, n] & /@ list2

(*  {"000", "001", "002", "010", "011", "012", "020", "021", "022", \
"100", "101", "102", "110", "111", "112", "120", "121", "122", "200", \
"201", "202", "210", "211", "212", "220", "221", "222"}  *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way to generate ternary number strings of a certain length.

```
ternaryStrings[len_Integer?Positive] := 
  StringJoin @@@ Map[ToString, Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, len], {2}]
```

With this

```
ternaryStrings[1]
```

> `{"0", "1", "2"}`

```
ternaryStrings[2]
```

> `{"00", "01", "02", "10", "11", "12", "20", "21", "22"}`

```
ternaryStrings[3]
```

> `{"000", "001", "002", "010", "011", "012", "020", "021", "022", 
>   "100", "101", "102", "110", "111", "112", "120", "121", "122", "200", 
>   "201", "202", "210", "211", "212", "220", "221", "222"}`

And so on.

You, of course, want to list all the ternary number strings of length 100, which I don't think is possible because there are $3^{100}$ such strings. Certainly, `ternaryStrings[100]` won't do it. *Mathematica* won't even try to generate all the 3-tuples of length 100.

```
Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 100]
```

> Tuples::toomany: The length of the output of Tuples[{0,1,2},100] should be a machine integer. >>
>
> `Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 100]`

#### Update

As J.M. points this my code can be simplified to

```
ternaryStrings[len_Integer?Positive] := StringJoin @@@ Tuples[{"0", "1", "2"}, len]
```

which will be considerably faster as well.

Comment: Why not just `Tuples[{"0", "1", "2"}, len]`?

Comment: @J.M. Indeed, why not? Because that simplication didn't occur to me.